# longitude/latitude values are not correct

Tags: ios, core-location

i try to catch the longitude and latitude values and to display them in the console (NSLog) for the moment, i  have puted the correspondant code in the `viewWillAppear` method, any way, it's not a big deal, my problem is when i show the view the first time, my console show me that:

```
latitude: 0.000000
longitude:0.000000
```

and the second time it shows me that :

```
latitude : 134217731.444448
longitude : 0.700000
```

the third time :

```
latitude : 134217731.444448
longitude : 0.700000
```

the n time :

```
 latitude : 134217731.444448
    longitude : 0.700000
```

this my code in the `viewWillAppear` (i'm sure it's logic is pretty right and i'm waiting for your clarification):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{   
    // locationManager update as location
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    // Configure the new event with information from the location
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude]; 
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"Latitude : %@", latitude); 
    NSLog(@"Longitude : %@",longitude);

}
```

note that i work on the iPhone simulator, thx for help :)))

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't check coordinate here.

Implement `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:` method in the same class and check the location inside this method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [newLocation coordinate];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude]; 
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];

    NSLog(@"Latitude : %@", latitude); 
    NSLog(@"Longitude : %@",longitude);

}
```

Your current class should implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol, i.e. it should be  a delegate of location manager.